# Как вернуть Int в методе String?

Tags: java, строки, int

```
public class Fizzbuzz {

    static String fizzbuzz(int number) {
    if(number % 3 != 0 && number % 5 != 0){
            return number;
        }
        else if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 != 0){
            return "fizz";
        }
        else if (number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 != 0){
            return "buzz";
        }
        else if (number % 5 == 0 && number % 3 == 0){
            return "fizzbuzz";
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Преобразовать в строку

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь статическим методом `valueOf` класса `String`:

```java
String.valueOf(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вернуть int в методе String никак нельзя, но можно вернуть текст, содержащий это число.

Пустой else совершенно не нужен, зачем он в коде? Остальное можно и нужно упростить:

```
static String fizzbuzz(int number { 
if (number % 15 == 0)
    { return "fizzbuzz"; }
else if (number % 3 == 0)
    { return "fizz"; }
else if (number % 5 == 0)
    { return "buzz"; }
else { return number.toString(); } // или String.ValueOf(number)
}
```